# Markov's like inequalities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

This sounds trivial but unfortunately I kind of feel lost in proving these:

which of the followings inequalities holds:

\begin{align}
&P(X\ge a)\leq\frac{E(X)}{a}\\
&P(X\ge a)<\frac{E(X)}{a}\\
&P(X> a)\leq\frac{E(X)}{a}\\
&P(X> a)<\frac{E(X)}{a}
\end{align}

For a non-negative constant $a$ and a random variable $X$.

I know the first one is Markov's inequality so it does hold, but what about the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them are false. If $0<a<EX$ the $\frac {EX} a >1$ and probability of an event cannot exceed $1$.

Answer for the reviser version of the question:

You also need $X$ to be non-negative. Otherwise the first one is also false.

Take $X=a$ w.p. $1$ to see that the second one  is false.

$P(X>a) \leq P(X \geq  a) \leq \frac {EX } a$.

To see the the fourth inequality can fail take $X=\pm \frac a 2$ with probability $\frac 1 2 $ each.

Comment: Oops!, I revised the question, there was some typo!, thanks for mentioning them.

Comment: Is it possible that from 1 or 3 one can conclude $P(X<a)\ge 1-\frac{E(X)}{a}$ and $P(X\leq a)\ge 1-\frac{E(X)}{a}$ respectively?

Comment: @Jason Yes, of course.